# How to I adjust this nested loop to store the output of different URL requests in separate databases or .csv files?

Tags: python, nested

so I'm working at a simple project but apparently I'm stuck at the first step. Basically I'm requesting the .json files from a public github repository. 7 different files which I aim to download and convert to 7 differently named databases.

I tried to use this nested loop, trying to create 7 different csv files, the only **problem is that it gives me 7 different named csv files with the same content** (the one from the last URL).
I think it has something to do with the way I store the data from the json output in the list "data".
How could I solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import re, json, requests #this is needed to import the data from the github repository

naz_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale-latest.json'
naz_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.json'
reg_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-latest.json'
reg_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.json'
prov_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province-latest.json'
prov_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json'
news_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-note.json'

list_of_url= [naz_l_url,naz_url, reg_l_url,reg_url,prov_url,prov_l_url,news_url]
csv_names = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07']

for i in list_of_url:
 resp = requests.get(i)
 data = pd.read_json(resp.text, convert_dates=True)
 for x in csv_names:
  data.to_csv(f"{x}_df.csv")
```

I want to try two different ways. 1 with the loop giving me csv files, and another with the loop giving me pd dataframes. But I need to solve the problem of the loop giving me the same output for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over the full list of names *for each URL* you download. Note how `for x in csv_names` is *inside* the `for i in list_of_url` loop.

### Where the problem comes from

Python uses indentation levels to determine when you are in and out of a loop (as other languages might use curly braces, `begin/end`, or `do/end`). I'd recommend you brush up on this topic. For example, with [Concept of Indentation in Python](https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/concept-of-indentation-in-python/). You can see the official documentation about [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html), too.

### Proposed solution

I'd recommend you replace the naming of the files, and do something like this instead:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import re, json, requests #this is needed to import the data from the github repository
from urllib.parse import urlparse

naz_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale-latest.json'
naz_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.json'
reg_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-latest.json'
reg_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.json'
prov_l_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province-latest.json'
prov_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-province.json'
news_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-json/dpc-covid19-ita-note.json'

list_of_url= [naz_l_url,naz_url, reg_l_url,reg_url,prov_url,prov_l_url,news_url]
csv_names = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07']

for url in list_of_url:
 resp = requests.get(url)
 data = pd.read_json(resp.text, convert_dates=True)
 # here is where you DON'T want to have a nested `for` loop
 file_name = urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1].replace('json', 'csv')
 data.to_csv(file_name)
```